# Performance measure of Continuous Integration in GoCD

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, go-cd

I need to measure the performance of my Continuous integration environment in GoCD, docker and GitHub repository. Could you please recommend me ant metrics for the evaluation. It is also be great if you recommend me how to apply those metrics.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean with 'performance of my CI environment'? Do you want to know how long it takes to build something? Are you looking for metrics such as cycle time and lead time or are you after something else?

Comment: Exactly. I need to measure the deploy and build time. Other related options with time can also help

Comment: GoCD has various dashboards and info that shows how long your build takes. Have you looked at the docs for GoCD?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two meaningful metrics: latency and throughput.

Latency answers the question "how long do I have to wait after a `git push` until the build (or whatever else) is finished"? and throughput answers the questions "how many builds per hour or day can I make?".

A system with a high latency can still have a high throughput, for example if it allows many builds in parallel.

For latency, you should put it into the context of how long your jobs themselves take. If a build takes 20 minutes, an added latency of 2 minutes introduced by your CI/CD system doesn't matter match; if the jobs is just 20s, an added 2 minutes latency can hurt a lot.